# "Parent", "Child" Classes In Ruby (Not Inheritance)

Tags: ruby, object-oriented-analysis

Let's say I have two classes.  One class, "parent", has many of another class "child".  This is not inheritance, I don't want parent methods to act on child objects.  What I want is the child object to be able to reference the parent object, get variables from it (child.parent.var) and call parent methods that modify the parent (`child.parent.update`).

I'd like one object (which could be thought of as a child-but-not-child-because-this-isn't-inheritance) to be passed a reference to another object when it is initialized.  I'd compare this to a parent child relationship in a database where we store info on the parent so we don't have to duplicate it onto every child.

Example:

```
class Parent
    attr_accessor :var

  def initialize(num)
    @var = num
  end

  def increase
    @var += 1
  end
end

class Child
    attr_accessor :var, :parent

    def initialize(parent, num)
        @parent = parent
        @var = num
    end

    def sum
        @parent.increase
        @parent.var + var
    end
end

parent1 = Parent.new(1)

child1 = Child.new(parent1, 2)
child2 = Child.new(parent1, 3)

child1.parent.increase # update the parent variable
child2.parent.var      # get the parent variable
```

The above code does work, but is there a better (more concise, or more ruby-esq) way to achieve this?

Thanks so much for your help/thoughts.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. This is a pretty great first-timer question. In the future, please try to describe a bit more the details of your problem. "It feels  odd" is a pretty vague description. That said while Stack Overflow tends towards hard code questions lately, questions of design and code structure are still on topic here. Just be sure to describe your actual problem. Often, http://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/ or http://codereview.stackexchange.com/ are great places for these kinds of questions too.

Comment: @HolgerJust when referring other sites, it is often helpful to point that [cross-posting is frowned upon](http://meta.stackexchange.com/tags/cross-posting/info)

Comment: @HolgerJust thanks for your wisdom my friend!  Still a newbie so I will take your advice on the next question :-)

Comment: Your question is unclear. The important bit of your question seems to be this: "Since ruby is pass-by-reference, what is the correct way to handle this?" However, your premise in untrue: Ruby is strictly pass-by-value, *never* pass-by-reference, so this seems to invalidate your entire question.

Comment: @JörgWMittag While it is true that Ruby is pass-by-reference-value, the question does not suffer from this slightly incorrect assumption. The main point on how to structure classes which reference and access other object still stands.

Comment: @JörgWMittag Thanks for pointing out the error, I'll update the question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is basically how it's supposed to be done :) There are a couple of possible improvements though, depending on what you actually want to achieve.

Right now, your `Child` instances expose access to the parent on their external interface (via the public `parent` accessor). This is often a violation of the [Law of Demeter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_Demeter) which states that objects should only talk to their direct neighbors. In this sense, the `parent` is a stranger when accessed though the child object.

You could improve your design by hiding the parent object:

```
class Child
  extend Forwardable

  def_delegator :@parent, :var, :parent_var
  def_delegator :@parent, :increase

  attr_accessor :var

  def initialize(parent, num)
    @parent = parent
    @var = num
  end

  def sum
    @parent.increase
    @parent.var + var
  end
end
```

Here, we use Ruby's [Forwardable](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib/libdoc/forwardable/rdoc/Forwardable.html) module to provide access to some methods of the parent from the client. This makes these methods part of the single public interface of your Child class.

```
parent = Parent.new(1)

child = Child.new(parent, 2)

child.var
# => 2
child.parent_var
# => 1
child.increase
# => 2
parent.var
# => 2
# ^^^^ the increase method was called on the parent object
```

From the outside, it doesn't matter that the methods are forwarded and you can later change this without affecting your external interface at all.

---

A second improvement could be to extend your `Parent` class to generate children directly:

```
class Parent
  # ...

  def child(num)
    Child.new(self, num)
  end
end
```

This is usually called a [Factory Method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_method_pattern), i.e. a method which builds other objects. With this, you can hide the complexity of building your Child objects and attaching them to your parent.

You can call it like

```
parent = Parent.new(1)
child = parent.child(2)
```